# SQL Server : FK relationship shows up for the child but not for the parent

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-2.2

This screenshot shows that there is a FK from `PurchaseOrderDetailHistory` to `Item`:

[image: PurchaseOrderDetailHistory FK to Item]

`Item` does not show `PurchaseOrderDetailHistory` has a dependency on it. (`PurchaseOrderDetail` is a different table - that is working):

[image: Item has no FK reference to PurchaseOrderDetailHistory]

The Gui not showing it wouldn't be a big deal, but EF Core also does not see the relationship. This is the easiest way to explain what is going on. I need to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try refreshing both tables, make sure you are checking on the same database and proper schema (there might be 2 tables "Item" on different schemas) and check if the foreign key is enabled.

Comment: the idea of two item tables in different schema's is interesting - it isn't the case but it is what the behavior would indicate.  As you can see above, the FK is enabled because it does show up where the PurchaseOrderDetailHistory is dependent on Item.  Thus Item should show that the PurchaseOrderDetailHisotry depends on it but it doesn't show it.  I can not figure out why.